# How to set Kendo editor as cell template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-template, kendo-editor

**Requirement 1:**
I need the user to the ability to edit content of the grid all the time, meaning as a `template`, the user should not be required click on the field and then the editor appears.

**Requirement 2:** I want a kendo editor for the user to enter/edit values.

The following is what I tried, since I don't know how to do this using template I tried out using `editor`

**Grid setup:**

```
                    dataSource: {
                    data: $scope.planOverviewModel,
                    sort: {
                        field: "TermName",
                        dir: "asc"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                TermName: { type: "string", editable: false },
                                InNetwork: { type: "string", editable: true },
                                OutNetwork: { type: "string", editable: true }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                columns: [
                    { field: "TermName", title: "Term" },
                    {
                        field: "InNetwork",
                        title: "In-Network",
                        editor: $scope.setupTextBox
                    },
                    {
                        field: "OutNetwork",
                        title: "Out-Network",
                        editor: $scope.setupTextBox
                    }
                ],
                editable: true,
                change: function (e) {
                    console.log("changed");
                    if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                        this.sync();
                    }
                }
```

**Editor setup:**

```
$scope.setupTextBox = function(container, options) {
    $('<textarea class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"> </textarea>')
        .appendTo(container).kendoEditor({
            resizable: {
                content: true,
                toolbar: true
            }
        });
};
```